# Running an OpenVINO Python script on boot for Raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, openvino, raspbian-buster

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 running Raspbian 10 (Buster). I want to run a python script on startup that uses OpenVINO and OpenCV to detect objects and display a stream from a webcam.

I created a shell script `launcher.sh` that contains

```
#!/bin/sh

/opt/inte/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/project/run.py
```

I ran `$ chmod 775 launcher.sh` and confirmed that the script works with `$ sh launcher.sh`.

To run the script on start up I used `$ sudo crontab -e` and added `@reboot sh /home/pi/project/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1` to the bottom.

The script does run on reboot. The logs **show that the OpenVINO environment is initialized**, but the logs also indicate I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino'. I'm guessing it only works when i run it from the terminal because I have my bash.rc setting up the OpenVINO env each time.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this on Buster?

Comment: Does your bash rc do anything else other than /opt/inte/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
?

Comment: hasn't been modified except for a single line that runs setupvars.sh

Comment: I guess you should call it like this: 'source /opt/inte/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh' to export all variables from setupvars.sh to the script where it is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mauricio.R from Intel I was able to find a proper solution.

1. Create a script that initializes OpenVINO and launches my python script using `nano ~/openvino-app-script` with contents:

```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh     
   /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script/run.py
```

2. Change the bash script's permissions and ownership with `chmod u+x ~/openvino-app-script`. You should make sure this script works by running it with `bash ./openvino-app-script`
3. Create a service file using `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/openvino-app.service` with contents

```sh
    [Unit]
    Description=OpenVINO Python Script
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
    Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"
    ExecStart=/home/pi/openvino-app-script
    WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
    StandardOutput=inherit
    StandardError=inherit
    Restart=on-failure
    User=pi

    [Install]
    WantedBy=graphical.target
```

4. Activate the service with `sudo systemctl enable openvino-app.service`

You can check the status or disable the service by changing `enable` to `disable` or `status`

This solution works great for my project, which displays a video-stream with an overlay using OpenCV and performs inference using an NCS.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to resolve my specific issue, but I did manage to find a way to run my script on boot.

I added the following lines the end of my .bashrc,

```
source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
cd /home/pi/project
python3 run.py 
cd
```

to initialize the OpenVINO environment and run my script every time a new terminal is opened, and then I made the LXTerminal run on boot by adding `@lxterminal` to the end of /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.

It's a pretty hacky way to do it and impractical if you're planning to use your Pi for anything else. Any advice would still be appreciated